# How do you delete a object once placed in the scene in a arcore based project

Tags: arcore

Once placed renderables i want to remove the if the need arises any help on the subject would be great

Answer (score 0):

set the parent of the node to null.

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it